# Ошибка в коде. Свойства get и set

Tags: c#

Есть два класса. В главном записываем три значения ( name, course, grand ). Дальше передаем их в класс Student. Я хочу, чтобы значение course выводилось правильно после проверки свойства set на меньше нуля или больше пяти.

```
class Program
{
    private static string name;
    private static int course;
    private static bool grand;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        course = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        grand = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());

        Student Andrew = new Student(name, course, grand);
        Console.WriteLine(Andrew.course);


        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

class Student
{
    private string name;
    public int course;
    private bool grand;


    public int Course
    {

        set
        {
            if (value < 1)
            {
                course = 1;
            }
            else if (value > 5)
            {
                course = 5;
            }

        }
    }


    public Student(string name, int course, bool grand)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
        this.grand = grand;
        print();
    }
    public void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        Console.WriteLine(course);
        Console.WriteLine(grand);
    }

}
```

Comment: Т.е. в конструкторе класса `Student` вместо `this.course = course;` написать `Course = course;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала нужно исправить ошибку: `public int course;` => `private int course;`. Не стоит нарушать принцип инкапсуляции, данные должны быть только внутри. И немного доведем до ума класс:

```
class Student
{
    //заменим автоматическим свойством, раз не нужна дополнительная логика
    //private string name; 
    //приватное поле и аксесоры будут добавлены при компиляции.
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //private bool grand;
    public bool Grand { get; set; }//смотри выше
    //для работы с этим полем нужна дополнительная логика, 
    //реализуем ее явно
    private int course;
    public int Course
    {
        get 
        { 
            return course; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 1)
            {
                course = 1;
            }
            else if (value > 5)
            {
                course = 5;
            }
            else 
            {
                course = value; 
            }
        }
    }
    public Student(string name, int course, bool grand)
    {
        //меняем обращение к полям, на обращение к свойствам
        Name = name;
        Course = course;//в сеттере прописана логика, и она будет применена
        Grand = grand;
        //print(); это явно лишнее в конструкторе, если конечно не относилось 
        //к отладочному коду. 
    }
    //этому место в классе `Program`, не стоит смешивать модель с представлением
    //public void print()
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine(name);
    //    Console.WriteLine(course);
    //    Console.WriteLine(grand);
    //}
}
```

После переноса. метод для печати может стать таким:

```
public void print(Student student)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(student.Course);
    Console.WriteLine(student.Grand);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
set {
    course = (value < 1)? 1: (value > 5)? 5: value;
}
```

Comment: Не поможет, потому что конструктор обращается не к свойству: _`this.course = course;`_.

Comment: я просто сократил длинные условия аксессора set

Comment: если ты допишешь в ответ про то, что надо ещё поменять конструктор, то это будет ответом. а пока - нет.

Comment: Это больше совет, чем ответ. Первый твой комментарий описывает общую концепцию инициализации свойств, но она и не отрицает возможность инициализации, как и в предыдущем ответе (неоднократно встречал в книгах и у других разработчиков).

Comment: если это не ответ, то он должен быть в комментариях, а не в ответах. но до ответа ему только одного момента не хватает - с конструктором.